VS2019 - VSIX - Cannot locate resource (.png) at runtime
I try to display an image in a WPF based VSIX
in the XAML designer, the image appears fine
<Image x:Name="waitImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/wpf/Resources/progress_1.png" />

but programmatically, the API complains it needs the assembly name, so I load it this way
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
ImageAnimationPath = $"pack://application:,,,/{assemblyName};component/wpf/Resources/progress_{imageIndex}.png";
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageAnimationPath));
imageIndex = (imageIndex % 3) + 1;

at runtime I get an error message :
"Cannot locate resource 'wpf/resources/progress_1.png'."

I expect:

the image to load fine
and be available at runtime when the VSIX is deployed or during debugging

I tried:

properties/copy always on the image
setting the Build action to Resource (the image disappears form the Solution explorer)
cleaning the solution

Any help appreciated

"setting the Build action to Resource" - this is what you have to do for a Resource File Pack URI as you have it. The image file does not need to be copied to the output directory.

as mentioned, the image disappears from the solution explorer. I meant I try different things one or the other, not both at the same time

"the image disappears from the solution explorer" - not sure what exactly that means. Are you saying that the file is no longer part of a Visual Studio project? Is it a (new) SDK-style project? If you set Resource as Build Action, does your code work at runtime?

it visualy disapears in the Solution explorer, it is still in the .projitem but as a , not as a , and it is still physically in the folder...anyway the error remains at runtime

1.Make sure that the image files are being included in the VSIX package when it's built. You can verify this by examining the contents of the VSIX package after building.
2.Ensure that the file path is correct based on the structure of your project. In your case, it seems like you're already using the correct format. However, double-check that the assembly name and path to the image resource are accurate.
3.Ensure that the casing of the folder and file names in the image path matches the actual casing of the folders and files in your project.

You could try the following code.
If the Build Action is Resource in the Properties window:
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/progress_1.png" />

If the Build Action is Content and Include in VSIX is True in the Properties window:
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/progress_1.png" />

Here are the corresponding code-behind methods to dynamically load the image based on whether the Build Action is set to Resource or Content:
If the Build Action is Resource in the Properties window:
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class YourWindow : Window
    {
        public YourWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            string imageUri = $"pack://application:,,,/{assemblyName};component/Resources/progress_1.png";
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUri));
            yourImageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}

If the Build Action is Content and Include in VSIX is True:
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class YourWindow : Window
    {
        public YourWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string imageUri = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/progress_1.png";
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUri));
            yourImageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
}

Replace YourNamespace with the actual namespace of your project, YourWindow with the name of your window class, and yourImageControl with the name of your Image control. These code-behind methods dynamically load the image based on the Build Action configuration.

What you are saying about the difference between Resource and Content File Pack URIs doesn't make much sense. Are you aware that a Resource File Pack URI may be written without the referenced assembly part and thus look identical to a Content File Pack URI? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf
